# Material-UI Changing default color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I change the default color ? 
What is the object I need to modify in the theme.js ?

EDIT

I want to modify the defaut (grey color) who isn't `primary` or `secondary` or `error`.

Comment: https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/

Comment: Different shades of grey are used in different places with the color coming from different parts of the theme. Please show an example (a CodeSandbox is particularly helpful) that shows the particular thing you want to override.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across a similar issue to the OP, specifically I wanted to change the default Button color from grey to white. The question commenters are correct, each component has its own specific styles and colors versus a global default color. These need to be overridden via a custom theme. Below is an example of overriding [Button's default class `contained`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L110), by creating a [theme override](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override) to change the default button color. `CONTANTS` is used to define the specific colors, etc.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import * as CONSTANTS from './Constants'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // light: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      main: CONSTANTS.BLUE,
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      contrastText: CONSTANTS.CONTRAST_TEXT,
    },
  },
  overrides:{
    MuiButton:{
      contained:{
        color: CONSTANTS.BLUE,
        backgroundColor: CONSTANTS.CONTRAST_TEXT,
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: CONSTANTS.LIGHT_BLUE,
          // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
          '@media (hover: none)': {
            backgroundColor: CONSTANTS.CONTRAST_TEXT,
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
interface IThemeProps{
  children:any;
}
export default function Theme(props: IThemeProps) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {props.children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

And to use the new theme:

```
import React from 'react';
import Theme from './Theme';
import { Header, Home } from './Components';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Theme>
      <Header>
        <Home />
      </Header>
    </Theme>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: So if default color is a color specific to a given component, such as Button regardless of the theme, doesn't it make more semantic sense, instead of overriding Button's default colour, to set the property 'color' of button to e.g. primary globally by default? (using https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#default-props - color: "primary")

Trying to understand the meaning of 'default' color. As it is *not* within palette color setting, I read it as it was meant only as a fallback and wasn't meant to be tinkered with.

Answer (score 2):

```
const customTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        outlined: {
          color: "red",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I found on Material UI documentation about overriding the default properties

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the palette object in the theme.

```
`palette: {
  primary: {
    light: palette.primary[300],
    main: palette.primary[500],
    dark: palette.primary[700],
    contrastText: getContrastText(palette.primary[500]),
  },
  secondary: {
    light: palette.secondary.A200,
    main: palette.secondary.A400,
    dark: palette.secondary.A700,
    contrastText: getContrastText(palette.secondary.A400),
  },enter code here
  error: {
    light: palette.error[300],
    main: palette.error[500],
    dark: palette.error[700],
    contrastText: getContrastText(palette.error[500]),
  },
},`
```

Comment: I want to modify the defaut (grey color) who isn't primary or secondary or error. Can I do it ?